# how can i make the lines variable in a file?

Tags: linux, bash

I am using a unix based program. I want to automate the code so as not to copy and paste data one by one. For this, I need to define line-by-line data in a file as a variable for the code

The program converts xyz coordinates to local coordinates. How can I run the coordinates in the xyz_coordinates file I created, one by one, in the code below? In the program I use, the conversion code works like this:

```bash
echo 4208830.039709186 2334850.551667509 4171267.377406844 -6.753E-01 4.493E-01 2.849E-01  | xyz2env.py
```

and this is the file i am trying to run:

```
2679689.926729193 -727950.9964290063 5722789.538975053 7.873E-02 3.466E-01 6.410E-01

2679689.927123377 -727950.9971557076 5722789.540522 7.912E-02 3.458E-01 6.425E-01

2679689.930567728 -727950.9979971027 5722789.550832021 8.257E-02 3.450E-01 6.528E-01

2679689.931029495 -727950.9992263148 5722789.549927638 8.303E-02 3.438E-01 6.519E-01

2679689.929031829 -727950.9981009626 5722789.546359798 8.103E-02 3.449E-01 6.484E-01

........
```

and it goes on like this. Also, there are spaces between the lines. Will this be a problem?

Comment: [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and [looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash)

Comment: Also, I believe xargs would be of help here.

Comment: did you try a simple `xyz2env.py < xyz_coordinates`?

Comment: yes but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xargs` to invoke the command for a specific number of arguments (6 in your case) and have the advantage of skipping empty lines automatically

```
< file.txt xargs -n 6 xyz2env.py
```